# SQL - Exec (string + null) - is this a bug or by design?

Tags: sql, sql-server

i was revising an an old sql query code and could not figure out why the new version wont work. Below is the simplest version of the code.

**--old version**

```
declare @query as varchar(10)
set @query = null
print 'test1'
exec('print ''a'''+@query+';print ''b''')
```

**--new version**

```
declare @query as varchar(10)
declare @text varchar(20)
set @text = null
set @query = 'print ''a'''+@text+';print ''b'''
print 'test2'
exec (@query)
```

**Results**

```
test1
a
b

test2
```

Running exec with strings + null automatically ignores null. is this by design or documented somewhere? or is this a bug? i must be missing something. could someone pls explain?

Could any one pls post mysql results? thanks.

Comment: The results for MySQL would be a bunch of syntax errors. (We can't declare user-defined variables; we can't run DECLARE statements outside of a stored program; `EXEC` is not a valid statement, et al.  The `+` operator would be interpreted as numeric addition, not string concatenation, etc.

Comment: This has nothing to do with MySQL, right?

Comment: This behavior is by design in SQL Server. The setting of `CONCAT_NULL_YIELDS_NULL` "Controls whether concatenation results are treated as null or empty string values." [http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms176056.aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms176056.aspx). (Return of `NULL` is consistent with ANSI specification, and consistent with results in other relational databases.)

Comment: @spencer7593 I don't think that explains why the behaviour differs between the two snippets above. One yields null, the other doesn't.

Comment: @Blorgbeard: I can't explain the behavior of the the `test1` results, except that the explicit or implicit setting of `CONCAT_NULL_YIELDS_NULL`. The referenced documentation gives an example of how to "check" the setting.

Comment: Somewhat interestingly, `set concat_null_yields_null on declare @query as varchar(10) = null exec('print ''concat_null_yields_null = '' '+ @query +';print case when 4096 & @@OPTIONS = 4096 then ''on'' else ''off'' end')` indicates it's on, although the query that printed the result was concatenated with null.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-nz/library/ms188332.aspx) states the syntax:

```
Execute a character string
{ EXEC | EXECUTE } 
    ( { @string_variable | [ N ]'tsql_string' } [ + ...n ] )
    [ AS {  USER } = ' name ' ]
[;]
```

So, my guess is that the `+` in the expression `'print ''a'''+@query+';print ''b'''` is not being interpreted as string concatenation, but simply as part of the syntax for the `exec` command.

That might explain why the behaviour is different; although not whether it's a bug or a feature.

Contrast the above with the documentation for [`print`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-nz/library/ms176047.aspx):

> ```
> PRINT msg_str | @local_variable | string_expr
> ```
>
> ...
>   string_expr
>       Is an expression that returns a string. Can include concatenated literal values, functions, and variables. For more information, see Expressions (Transact-SQL).

Notice that `print` just refers to a "string expression", where `exec` defines its own syntax.

Comment: I think I understand now. it's probably treating the null values as [ + ...n ] or a different parameter. since it's null, it ignores that parameter.